# Transformers and electric potential

Tags: transformer

Suppose I have a 1:1 transformer, just to keep things simple. The primary winding is connected to mains voltage (±170V peaks), with a grounded neutral. The secondary winding has an arbitrary load.

If we measured the voltage across the secondary winding, it would be a 120V RMS sin wave. So that's the potential difference.

But what determines the *absolute* potential of each terminal on the secondary winding? In other words, what will the potential be relative to ground? Or is the absolute potential not referenced to ground at all, and instead referenced to the local electric field in the transformer?

Answer (score 4):

In the first approximation**, the potential of the secondary winding is not referenced to the primary side ground.  Primary and secondary sides each have its own ground, which are floating with respect to each other.  This is why transformers are used for galvanic isolation (among other things).

** Without considering leakages, capacitive coupling, dielectric breakdown

[image]

Comment: Practical effect: if you're working with mains voltage, the secondary winding either has to be either a) tied to the same earth reference as the primary, so that no hazardous voltage difference can exist, or b) double-insulated from the user, so the user isn't exposed to the floating potential on the secondary.

Comment: @Li-aungYip  Can't agree with either (at least in the way that it's written).  I think, what you have in mind is this.  **a)** Class I appliance.  Chassis is earthed.  If there is unearthed "dead" metal, it's insulated from both pri and sec.  **b)** Class II (or double insulated) appliance.  Sec is double insulated from pri.  Low voltage sec is not insulated from the user.  **Everyday example:** Wall-warts are double-insulated between pri and sec.  At the same time, sec side is exposed.   [More on appliance classes here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes)

Comment: You're right, of course. My main point was that you either want to earth everything, or insulate everything.

Comment: This gets at another point I was wondering about: If the voltages are floating relative to each other, what affects their relationship? I.e. the offset between the primary side's positive peak and the negative side's primary peak is a function of what?

Comment: @Jarrett  In the ideal xfrmr, the DC offset between primary and secondary sides is undefined, and it can be anything.  In practice, there is leakage (modeled as a large value resistor between pri and sec grounds) and breakdown of dielectric if the voltage between pri and sec is too high.

Comment: @Jarrett  Fun fact.  Spice simulation would get upset if you try to simulate a circuit with an ideal xfrmr and completely isolated primary and secondary.  The way to prevent Spice from getting upset is to add a large value resistor (10MΩ) between pri and sec grounds.

Comment: Just want to correct my horrible typo in case anyone finds it confusing. "Negative side's primary peak" should be "secondary side's positive peak." Embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

A transformer of this type is an isolating transformer. You can make a fairly inefficient isolating transformer by using two coils of wire in close proximity to each other (don't try this at home on power ac). They don't need to be touching and the two coils can have an air gap between them.

The ac voltage applied to one coil will generate an alternating magnetic and this field will induce voltage in the other coil. The secondary coil (receiving the magnetism) isn't connected to anything - just like a moving coil microphone produces a small voltage across its terminals when sounds are picked-up on the coil diaphragm.

What about a battery - what determines the absolute potential on each terminal - in actual fact there is no universal 0V or ground - voltages are just potential differences - there is no such thing as an absolute potential like you might be referring to.

Comment: I've read physics texts which speak of absolute potential in the sense that the electric field has a value at all points in space. Granted, your choice of reference for 0V is arbitrary. E.g. you could choose ground, or something else. For your battery example, it's my understanding that at least one of the terminals *would* be at a different potential than ground. (Since they're different from each other, they can't both be equal to ground.) But I also don't believe you could measure this easily, as a voltmeter won't read from one battery terminal to ground.